# Where can I find definition of starred version of \chapter command to redefine it

Tags: sectioning, chapters, document-classes, documentclass-writing

## General question

I need to redefine how starred version of `\chapter` command (that is `\chapter*`) works in `book` class.

I found definition of not-starred version of \chapter command in [`book` class](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls):

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

According [to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418727/1226389) there should be `@ifstar` somewhere inside that definition, but I can not find it.

**How and where is starred version of `\chapter` defined then?**

---

## My specific case

To give general idea why I need this here is explaination:

I have document which require me that chapter headings consist of two parts: (1) Descriptive chapter number (Chapter One etc. so it can't use regular `\chapter` command) and (2) descriptive title below number that can be long. I was able to push descriptive title below chapter number and style it according to my needs with following macro:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def \mylongchapter#1#2{
\chapter*{\centering{\LARGE #1} \\* \textnormal{\Large #2}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1: #2}
}

\begin{document}

\mylongchapter{Chapter One}{This Chapter Have Very Interesting and Long Title Below Chapter Number}

\lipsum[11-30]

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

I want to control spacing between two lines of chapter headings (space marked with red lines on screenshot):

[image]

Comment: To debug, go back to `book.cls` find the definition of `\chapter`, it ends with `\secdef\@chapter\@schapter`, so one of these are the normal, the other is the starred. Actually you will find `\@makechapterhead` just below the mabove line, and a little further down you will bind the starred equivalent to the code you posted.

Comment: I think, it is `\@schapter`

Comment: BTW: If you do not know your way around a class file, why are you rewriting like this anyway instead of using a package like `titlesec`?

Comment: What should your `\chapter*` command do?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need to control (decrease) spacing between lines of ``\chapter*`` heading and I figured out that I should use ``\onehalfspacing`` command from ``setspace`` package. So I am trying to re-define ``\chapter*`` so I can use that command inside of it.

Comment: Please post an MWE so that users can get an impression how it should like in the end

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have posted MWE to show what I need it for. I was unable to re-define ``\chapter*`` so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the definition of `\@makeschapterhead`, by adding `\centering inside and the custom spacing command`\mycustomspacing[factor]`, all applied in a group, so outside spacing is not affected!

I my code I used a factor of `0.8`, it works, but it does not look good, from a typographical point of view.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter


\newrobustcmd{\mynewstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\mynewstarredchapter@opt}{\mynewstarredchapter@noopt}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\mynewunstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\mynewunstarredchapter@opt}{\mynewunstarredchapter@noopt}%
}%

\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%

\newrobustcmd{\mycustomspacing}[1][1.0]{%
\let\originalbaselineskip\baselineskip
\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1\originalbaselineskip}%
}%


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%  
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    {  
    \Huge \bfseries \centering\mycustomspacing[0.8]#1 \par\nobreak
    }
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}




\newrobustcmd{\mynewunstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\mynewunstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\mynewstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#2}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\mynewstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}%
}%




\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\mynewstarredchapter}{\mynewunstarredchapter}%
}%


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\chapter*{Starred First}
\blindtext
\chapter[Second]{2nd Chapter}
\blindtext

\chapter*[Well, useless so far]{2nd starred chapter}
\blindtext





\chapter*{This Chapter Have Very Interesting and Long Title Below Chapter Number}%

%\chapter*[Well, useless so far]{3nd starred chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Requested reduced version, without starred redefinition ...**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycustomspacing}[1][1.0]{%
\let\originalbaselineskip\baselineskip%
\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1\originalbaselineskip}%
}%


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%  
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    {%  
    \Huge \bfseries \centering\mycustomspacing[0.8]#1 \par\nobreak
    }%
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter*{This Chapter Have Very Interesting and Long Title Below Chapter Number}%

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: My original comment under question was unclear what spacing I meant. I have added information to question for clarity. What you presented in first part of your answer is spacing above and below chapter heading. I need to manipulate spacing between lines of chapter headings.

Comment: I think, that you should rather use `\singlespacing` instead of `\onehalfspacing`

Comment: I figured it out too, three minutes ago :) ``\onehalfspacing`` doesn't change anything (I guess it is default). `\singlespacing`` decreases this space, though not to extent I would like it to, unfortunately. So I still don't have perfect solution. One would think there should be some easy way to control line spacing in headings, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you have solved my problem. One quesiton though - is this really minimal possible amount of code/definitions needed for it to work? I am not sure if all those ``\newrobustcmd`` commands are needed there. I tried to comment parts of code to figure it out, but I still do not have any success in compressing this code to minimal size required for it to work.

Comment: I will reduce to a minimum, it was old code according to the `starred` chapter issue. Give me some minutes, please ;-)

Comment: Sure and thanks :) I thought so as most of that code looked familiar.

Comment: Updated, `blindtext` can be removed too, if needed ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spend so much time trying to figure this out, that I can't believe it's finally done :)

Comment: @Rafal: Already, I learned also something through this, the new knowledge will help me too.

Answer (score 11):

The definition of `\chapter` doesn't have `\@ifstar`:

```
% book.cls, line 360:
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

The `\secdef` macro has `\@ifstar`; it's a general purpose macro used also for `\part`; what happens when `\chapter` is found is that some action are performed (a possible `\cleardoublepage`, the setting of the page style, disallowing top floats for the page and declaring no indentation for the first paragraph after the chapter title) and then

```
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter
```

is executed. The definition of `\secdef` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 5731:
\def\secdef#1#2{\@ifstar{#2}{\@dblarg{#1}}}
```

so here is `\@ifstar`. Basically, when `\chapter*{Title}` appears, LaTeX will find

```
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter*{Title}
```

which becomes

```
\@ifstar{\@schapter}{\@dblarg{\@chapter}}*{Title}
```

Since `*` follows, this becomes

```
\@schapter{Title}
```

Now what's `\@schapter`? Here it is

```
% book.cls, line 400:
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
```

so this makes pretty clear that the bulk of the work is done by `\@makeschapterhead`.